# Scala: How do you pass a method: Int => Boolean with 'not' operator?

Tags: scala

```
def isZero(x: Int) = x == 0

def eval(x: Int, g: Int => Boolean) = g(x)

//Just passes 0 and f to eval
def passToEval(f: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
    eval(0, f)
}

//true
passToEval(isZero)
```

The question is, how can I pass !f to the method, eval? 
I am not interested in workarounds involving the parameter of passToEval

Comment: You particularly don't what to write `passToEval(x => !isZero(x))`?

Comment: Right, I want the parameter of eval to handle that logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a function to negate its input function and pass that:

```
def not[A](f: A => Boolean) = (x: A) => !f(x)

passToEval(not(isZero))
```

Comment: Any way to avoid altering the param of passToEval?

Comment: You could move the `not` to be in passToEval i.e. `eval(0,not(f))`